# How to refresh cells (decrement from time inside lanes, utc, and show new value) in separate thread to avoid blocking UI?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have in custom cell inside UITableView time label and I need to decrement every 10 milliseconds until it reaches zero. How to refresh cells (decrement from time inside lanes, utc, and show new value) in separate thread to avoid blocking UI ?

Comment: Given that you have to update the `UILabel` on the main thread, what are you anticipating having to do that is going to block the UI?

Answer (score 1):

This works. If you need to do it every 10 ms, set up an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>];
```